# MVC4 two drop downs one view

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem where I cannot seem to figure out how to take data from two different models and populate two different drop downs in a view. I'm very new to MVC so please be kind, I am only learning.

First Product model:

```
public partial class Materials_Product
{
    public Materials_Product()
    {
        this.Materials_PackerProduct = new HashSet<Materials_PackerProduct>();
    }
    public short MatProdID { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }  
    public virtual ICollection<Materials_PackerProduct> Materials_PackerProduct { get; set; }
}
```

Second model:

```
public partial class Materials_Packer
{
    public Materials_Packer()
    {
        this.Materials_PackerProduct = new HashSet<Materials_PackerProduct>();
    }
    public short MatPackID { get; set; }
    public string PackerName { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Materials_PackerProduct> Materials_PackerProduct { get; set; }
}
```

Assign method inside my controller:

```
public ActionResult Assign()
{
    ViewBag.CategoryList = new SelectList(db.Materials_Product.ToList(), "MatProdID", "Product");
    ViewBag.ProductList = new SelectList(
        (from s in db.Materials_Product.ToList() select new
        {
            MatProdID = s.MatProdID,
            Product = s.Product + " " + s.Size
        }),
        "MatProdID",
        "Product");
    ViewBag.UserList = new SelectList(db.Materials_Packer.ToList(), "MatPackID", "PackerName");
    return View();
}
```

DBContext:

```
public partial class FreshouseSalesEntities : DbContext
{
    public FreshouseSalesEntities() : base("name=FreshouseSalesEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }
    public DbSet<Materials_Packer> Materials_Packer { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Materials_Product> Materials_Product { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Materials_PackerProduct> Materials_PackerProduct { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Materials_Vendor> Materials_Vendor { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Materials_Log> Materials_Log { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BigViewModel> BigViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

My view:

```
@model BagInventory.Models.Materials_Product
//I wish to  do something like @model BagInventory.Models.Materials_Packer but cannot since I believe I can only inherit one class
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Assign";
}
<h2>Assign</h2>
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MatProdID, ViewBag.ProductList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
<br />
<select id ="sltProduct">
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.ProductList) { 
        <option>@item.MatProdID</option>
    }
</select>
```

I cannot load two models in my view....

I read that you can make another model that contains properties of both models... it looks as follows (and does not work):

```
public class BigViewModel
{
    public Materials_Packer Materials_Packer { get; set; }
    public Materials_Product Materials_Product { get; set; }
}
```

Any guidance or direction would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is what I have tried using the 'BigViewModel' - aka both data models in one class:

```
public ActionResult Assign()
{
    ViewBag.ProductList = new SelectList(db.BigViewModel.ToList(), "MatProdID", "Product");
    ViewBag.UserList = new SelectList(db.BigViewModel.ToList(), "MatPackID", "PackerName");
    return View();
}
```

Updated view:

```
@model BagInventory.Models.BigViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Assign";
}

<h2>Assign</h2>
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Materials_Product.MatProdID, ViewBag.ProductList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
<br />
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Materials_Packer.MatPackID, ViewBag.ProductList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
```

Comment: what you mean by does not work? can you show how you did that?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad In my controller I called a new instance of BigViewModel BigViewModel bmv = new BigViewModel();
ViewBag.ProductList = new SelectList(bmv.Materials_Packer.ToList())   ToList is not available...

Comment: What I am really trying to accomplish is to take data from two different models and load it into one view. I have read about this but have had no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

view bag has its uses but you really want to try to avoid it.  change your model to be

```
public class BigViewModel
{
    public Materials_Packer mPacker { get; set; }
    public Materials_Product mProduct { get; set; }
    SelectList ProductList { get; set; }
    SelectList UserList { get; set; }
}
```

I would recommend not using the class name as the instance name.  I have run into issues in the past where the compiler was confused by that.
then on your controller you can set the lists

```
public ActionResult Assign() {
    BigViewModel vm = new BigViewModel();
    vm.ProductList = new SelectList(db.BigViewModel.ToList(), "MatProdID", "Product");
    vm.UserList = new SelectList(db.BigViewModel.ToList(), "MatPackID", "PackerName");
    return View(vm);
}
```

your drop downs will now be changed to

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Materials_Product.MatProdID, Model.ProductList)
```

Comment: Hm, now I get this error: "cannot implicitly convert type system.web.mvc.selectlist to system.collections.generic list". Also should I make List<SelectListItem> --- > public List<SelectListItem>?

Comment: if memory serves the public is default so I don't think that will change anything.  change the List<SelectListItem> to SelectList and it should fix the error you're getting

Comment: Didn't mean to make a difference.. I changed List to IEnumerable but that still doesn't fix it. I get: "The entity type BigViewModel is not part of the model for the current context" as an error now.

Comment: see my edit above for what I was suggesting you change.  I would suggest you change your name also so it doesn't match.  your view model is bigviewmodel but it looks like what you are getting back from the database is also bigviewmodel.  probably some confusion by the compiler there.

Comment: thank you for your help. You really steered me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

The issue that you appear to be encountering is the conceptual notion of a `Model` for the `View`.  Model View Controller is designed to represent the stateless nature of Hypertext Transfer Protocol.  So a `Model` by nature should represent the data for the page.

In theory you could use `Html.RenderAction`, this will write directly to the underlying response stream.  So, your *Partial View* will actually call the following through Razor:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("Model", "View"); }
```

However, I'm not sure that would be ideal approach for your architecture.  If you want more information about the above approach, a nice explanation can be found [here](http://www.arrangeactassert.com/when-to-use-html-renderpartial-and-html-renderaction-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-views/).

Otherwise the other approach would be similar to the following:

```
public class Packer
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Company { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

At this stage we have *two* distinct separate models.  Which resonate specific information for either a *Packer* or a *Product*.  So what we would do would be to do a larger model which embodies these smaller distinct models.

```
public string Shipping
{
     private List<Packer> packer;
     private List<Product> product;
     public Shipping(List<Packer> packer, List<Product> product)
     {
          this.packer = packer;
          this.product = product;
     }

     public List<Packer> Package
     {
          get { return this.packer; }
          set { this.packer = value; }
     }

     public List<Product> Products
     {
          get { return this.product; }
          set { this.product = value; }
     }
}
```

The above will create a `Shipping` model, which contains your two distinct and separate models.  So when your *Controller* calls either your service or domain layer, it would build the following *shipping* object.

From that stage, your Controller would simply pass *Shipping* to it which will be exposed to your *View State*.  The easiest way to see the approach above working, though it isn't recommended to do this in a Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Example()
{
     var products = new List<Product>();
     var packers = new List<Packer>();
     using(var connection = new SqlConnection(...))
          using(var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
          {
               // Query would grab all your data.
               using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    while(reader.Read())
                    {
                         var packer = new Packer();
                         var product = new Product();

                         // Build Your Model

                         packers.Add(packer);
                         products.Add(product);
                    }
          }

     var shipping = new Shipping(packers, products);
     return View(shipping, "Index");
}
```

That would be the premise of how to accomplish said goal.  Hopefully that helps you out.  I would also recommend not using `ViewBag`, due to how dynamic it is it can make maintenance difficult in the future.